# how to fix footer at specific height as per content and it get enlarged if content increased

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please tell me how to fix a footer at specific height and it will get down as per content
 its not working properly i want to fix it at specific height.

Thanks Mayur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
.footer{
min-height:50px;
height:auto;
}
```